# How to set delay time for incoming messages in camel route?

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

hen 3, 4 messages recieved at a time, my document status is not behaving as expected.

here i want to keep a delay time between the incoming messages.
can any one please suggest how to do it.

ActiveMQ is used for my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the receiveTimeout(default = 1000ms) option on your activemq endpoint.
See http://camel.apache.org/jms.html for more information.

Comment: Hi Soilworker,

 <from uri="activemq:{{queue.DMS.fromCUSTOMSEDI}}?concurrentConsumers=10&receiveTimeout=900;" />

getting below error after setting recieveTimeout

Offending resource: class path resource [dms-import-applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 334 in XML d
ocument from class path resource [dms-import-drools-applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 334; columnNumber: 99; The referen
ce to entity "receiveTimeout" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: it saying must end with ';' delimiter

Comment: can you post the whole xml? looks like a typo

Comment: Why you want to have concurrentConsumers if you want to delay your messages?

Comment: Hi Soliworker,
thanks for reply.
really iam new to camel.  can you explain me what is conflict between concurrentConsumers and recieveTimeout?
concurrentConsumers means no of threads should process the message. is it?

Comment: added my xml in the description.

Comment: If you specify concurrentConsumers = 10 then 10 threads will be startet that listen to your queue. This means that also 10 messages can be processed at the "same" time. Do you want to process the messages sequentially? Then just use 1 concurrentConsumer and I think then you don't need the receiveTimeout option.